# Acces 2010 filtrar lista por ultima fecha

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

Tengo una tabla de pesos vinculada a una lista de animales. Cada animal se debe pesar semanalmente pero no siempre se dejan por eso algunos tienen mas pesos registrados que otros. Lo que yo necesito es una consulta me devuelva solamente el ultimo peso de cada animal que no necesariamente va a tener la misma fecha ya que como dije, no siempre se logra.

esta consulta me devuelve la lista de pesos ordenados por fecha pero no se como limitarla

```
SELECT Animales.Nombre, Pesos.Peso, Max(Pesos.Fecha) AS MáxDeFecha
FROM Animales INNER JOIN Pesos ON Animales.Id = Pesos.IdAnimal
GROUP BY Animales.Nombre, Pesos.Peso;
```

Alguna idea porfis, tengo conocimientos minimos de `VBA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero y muy importante. Esto no es VBA, es SQL. aca VBA no tiene nada que ver, salvo que vayas a programar en VBA.

Sacandonos eso de encima, este problema se resuelve concatenando dos querys, una que traiga las maximas fechas por animal, y despues agregando el peso.

```
SELECT Pesos.IdAnimal, Max(Pesos.Fecha) AS MáxDeFecha
FROM Pesos 
GROUP BY Pesos.IdAnimal; //A esta consulta la llamamos consulta1
```

Esta consulta nos trae para cada animal, la ultima vez que fue pesado. Ahora solo necesitamos agregar su nombre y el peso de esa fecha.

Para ello la usamos como entrada de otra consulta, donde ahi si hagamos el join consigo mismo.

```
SELECT P.IdAnimal, P.Peso, c.MáxDeFecha
FROM Pesos inner join (consulta1) c on c.MáxDeFecha = P.Fecha;
```

Con esta consulta tenemos los pesos de la ultima fecha.. y ahora, solo nos falta el nombre..

Esto se puede simplicar sin un join, reutilizando la consulta anterior:

```
SELECT (SELECT A.Nombre From animales where a.Id = P.IdAnimal) as Nombre, P.Peso, c.MáxDeFecha
FROM Pesos inner join (consulta1) c on c.MáxDeFecha = P.Fecha;
```

Recordar que donde dice consulta1, debe ir toda la consulta que hicimos al principio.

Comment: Solo mencioné VBA porque a veces se encuentran soluciones haciendo modulos o procedimientos en VBA.
La primera consulta funcionó, la segunda no supe hacerla funcionar. Donde dice P.Peso lo sustituí por Pesos.Peso pero no se como llamar a la consulta1.
La guardé para poder llamarla y aún asi no me funciona. Me da alrededor de 300 registros todos repetidos.

Comment: No. Donde dice consulta1, escribit todo el sql que esta en la consulta 1. O guardala como una consulta aparte, y llamala... @AmpersandBlack

Comment: La primer consutla no deberia repetirte animales, salvo que este mal la tabla. SI no, agrega en tu pregunta los datos @AmpersandBlack

Comment: La primera consulta funciono a la perfeccion. Las otras acabo de lograr hacerlas, no se que estaba haciendo mal por codigo pero decidi lograr hacerla en vista de diseño y lo logré. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la atención!!!!!!!

Comment: Perfecto.. La respuesta esta bien o hay que hacerle algun cambio? recuerda como funciona el sitio y aceptar las respuestas que sirvieron. aprovecha y hace el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos..

Comment: Como lo hice mediante asistente de diseño lo hizo todo mediante JOIN asi que la tercera consulta no fue necesaria (aunque obviamente seria mas simple). la primera consulta la guardé como "mcs_ultimos_pesos" y así quedo.

SELECT Animales.Nombre, Pesos.Peso, mcs_ultimos_pesos.MáxDeFecha
FROM Animales INNER JOIN (mcs_ultimos_pesos INNER JOIN Pesos ON mcs_ultimos_pesos.IdAnimal = Pesos.IdAnimal) ON Animales.Id = Pesos.IdAnimal
WHERE (((mcs_ultimos_pesos.MáxDeFecha)=[Pesos].[Fecha]))
GROUP BY Animales.Nombre, Pesos.Peso, mcs_ultimos_pesos.MáxDeFecha, Animales.Id
ORDER BY Animales.Id;